# uncertainty sensitivity analysis with Pomp package Latin hypercube sampling

Tags: r

I did an uncertainty analysis a year ago using Pomp package. The aim was to quantify the impact of the variation of each parameter used on the outcome variable (Rhv). I combined uncertainty analysis through Latin hypercube sampling (LHS) with the sensitivity analysis through robust Partial rank correlation coefficient (PRCC) method.
Now that I try to update this work, it doesn't work anymore. I would love some help if possible. Sorry for the long post.

Example:

```
##### 1.explain data
library(pomp)
AvgT <- c(19, 30)
b <- 0.0047 * AvgT + 0.0467
Bm <- c(0.37, 0.67)    
Bh <- c(0.17, 0.73)    
eta <- c(0,0.4)
teta <- c(0.1, 0.57)
gammaH <- c(1/8, 1/3)
gammaHl <- c(1/6, 1/4)
gammav <- c(1/10, 1/7)
Ml <- c(0, 200.104)
Hl <- c(0.1352, 30.1182)
c <- c(0.1, 0.3)
muv <- c(1/30,1/3)

##### 2.do the Latin hypercube sampling method to generate 100 000samples
scalars1 <- sobol(vars=list(b = b, Bm = Bm, Bh = Bh,
                            eta = eta, teta = teta, c = c, muv = muv,
                            gammaH = gammaH, gammaHl = gammaHl, gammav = gammav,
                            Ml = Ml, Hl = Hl, AvgT = AvgT), 
                  1e+05)
```

I now got this message, while it was working perfectly a year ago. I know that Pomp package has been updated.

> Error in sobol(vars = list(b = b, Bm = Bm, Bh = Bh, eta = eta, teta =
>   teta,  :    could not find function "sobol"

Normally after that I was running:

```r
##### 3.create the function
Rhv <- function(b, Bm, Bh, eta, teta, c, gammaH, gammaHl, gammav, muv,
               Ml, Hl, AvgT) {
  sqrt((((b * b * eta * Bm * Bh * ((Ml * c) / (Hl)) * teta) * (1 / gammaH * 1 / muv))
        + ((b * b * Bm * Bh * ((Ml * c) / Hl) * teta) * (1 / gammaHl * 1 / muv))) *
       ((1 / gammav) / (((1 / gammav + 1 / muv)))))
  }
##### 4. do.call allows to call function with names as list 
vals1<- do.call(Rhv, scalars1)

##### 5. bind the columns with scalars results and R0
Both1 <- cbind(scalars1, Rhv=vals1)
head(Both1)
[example data Both1][1]

#####6.PRCC analysis
library('epiR')
```

and then a boxplot to get the final figure I need:
[example of boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcvQR.png)

Answer (score 0):

`sobol` as a standalone function was removed from package `pomp` years ago with version `0.65-1`. You must use function `sobolDesign` instead.

Check the online help (`?pomp::sobolDesign`), or the [`pomp` package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomp/pomp.pdf) section `design`.